# How to implement exactly once read semantics using Kafka Transaction API?

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka.
I want to design a system using Springboot+Kafka which will consume messages in a batch with exactly once read guarantee. The same message should not be processed again. I was supposed to use zookeeper's metadata which maintains the partition offset but then I came to know that Kafka has introduced Transaction API which takes care of this.
From documentation I read about this API but I did not find any practical sample example which shows that messages are processed only once.
Is there any link where I can learn Transaction API theoretically as well as implement it practically? Appreciate your help.

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

Comment: @cricket_007 I read about this. But I want sample spring boot+kafka transaction example to check whether it really works for exactly once read semantics.

Comment: Do you mean Spring Kafka? Have you checked the Spring documentation? Spring Kafka isn't a special installation of the Kafka clients, so enabling transactions is just a property like any other such as request timeouts

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I got your point. I want a sample example of spring which have used kafka Transaction API. Any example link regarding this would be helpful for me.